# SSH forced command parameters

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I'm attempting to write a script that verifies user permissions after a successful ssh login.

I'm doing this through an SSH forced command. I'd like to pass the script parameters (such as the user it is authenticating) but I'm not sure how I would do that.

Any help?

Comment: What is "an SSH forced command"?  Can you show us the commands you're trying to use?  It's very hard to debug code that you can't see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out on my own. You can pass parameters to the forced command script by setting environment variables and reading them in in the forced command script.

Comment: But you can only do this for environment variables set to be passed and accepted in the SSH client and daemon.

https://superuser.com/questions/48783/how-can-i-pass-an-environment-variable-through-an-ssh-command

Answer (score 2):

You can set a `ForcedCommand` in the sshd configuration file, or better inside an `authorized_keys` file of the respective user.

ssh executes sets the environment variable SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND to the complete commandline sent to the server and then executes `ForcedCommand`.

Writing scripts that make use of this environment variable for providing arguments has security implications, since an attacker might add e.g. `; rm -rf /` at the end of the commandline.  Then first the `ForcedCommand` would be run, and then `rm -rf /`.

[This article](http://at.magma-soft.at/sw/blog/posts/The_Only_Way_For_SSH_Forced_Commands/) describes a script, which can be used to generically lock down allowed commandlines.  It also contains links to relevant information.

The mechanism is as follows:

1. Put the script (only) as `ForcedCommand`
2. Add allowed 'real' commands as parameters
3. Add a rules file (`.onlyrules`) in the home directory of the respective user account, which restricts allowable parameters to the real command.

The only script reads the SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND checks if the command is a) allowed (in the list of parameters) b) is on the users PATH and then checks if the parameters pass the rules (in our case simple sed(1) scripts.

An example set up:

```
ForcedCommand /usr/local/bin/only ls
```

or `authorized_keys`:

```
command="/usr/local/bin/only ls" ssh-rsa AAAA...
```

`.onlyrules`

```
\:^ls /tmp$:{p;q}
```

This would only allow to send the command `ls /tmp` to the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

SSH does not allow passing password through parameters (or even through pipe) it is made by design, and even described in `man` page. Only way of automated login through ssh is by file authentication.

I think you can try to compare password provided by user, with values in /etc/shadow. That should do the trick :)

Comment: I'm not necessarily trying to pass the password as a parameter, but I'm wondering how or what gets passed to the forced command script as a parameter.

Comment: there's an ssh option called forced_command that you can force ssh to run when it logs in.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your `somehost.com` server is configured to run the forced command `your-script.sh` for `someuser`.

If you do:

```
ssh someuser@somehost arg1 arg2 'arg3 with spaces' arg4
```

Then ssh will automatically generate the env variable `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` with the following value:

```
arg1 arg2 arg3 with spaces arg4
```

And then will call `your-script.sh` with that env variable. Note that you lose information about arguments with spaces, unfortunately.

Therefore, you could do something as follows in `your-script.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -Eeuo pipefail

echo 'Hello from your forced SSH command!'
echo "After joining with spaces all arguments you passed, I got '${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND-}'."
```

**WARNING:** Be extremely careful on how you use the contents of the `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` variable, because it is a great attack surface for cyberattacks.

In particular, if you're using a shell script like in my example, NEVER use it in a way that would allow globbing and word splitting, and never perform `eval` on it or run it as a command, because that would be super unsafe.

Writing a safe shell script that processes arguments like this is hard. Make sure you know what you're doing. Also please use a tool like [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to help you catch mistakes.

Of course, recall that the Forced SSH Command does not have to be a shell script. It can be a Python script for example, which is probably easier to do right (although of course you still have to pay attention).